# SELinux: chcon to a type, ls -Z shows another one

Tags: selinux

When I do

```
chcon -v -t httpd_sys_script_ro_t a_folder_at_home/
```

And then:

```
ls -dZ
```

I got:

```
DACs user grp unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 a_folder_at_home/
```

In case of error I would have expected something like:

```
chcon -v -t httpd_sys_ro_content_t a_folder_at_home/
chcon: failed to change context of `a_folter_at_home/' to `unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_ro_content_t:s0': Invalid argument
```

Is this some kind of alias?

I am using Scientific Linux 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the line

```
typealias httpd_$1_content_t alias httpd_$1_script_ro_t;
```

[in the reference policy](https://github.com/TresysTechnology/refpolicy-contrib/blob/557b097ed8176846a4b4113f92bfeaceb8525d51/apache.if#L38) defines the script_ro types as aliases of their respective content types.

The kernel will use the canonical types, ie the content types.